# Multiple Developers for TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

We are two developers each with an *Individual* apple developer membership. One of us (developer A) set up a test flight and was able to distribute the app. Then, A added developer B to developer A's team through App Store Connect under Users and Access. We added developer B as an *App Manager*.

Now, both developer A and B can build the app with the same bundle identifier. However, when developer B tries to upload to TestFlight through Product > Archive > Distribute App, the following error occurs

> ERROR ITMS-90159: "Invalid provisioning profile. This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID 6UM2GR5MVA."

I have no idea what this means.

Our goal is just to each be able to *build and push* to TestFlight.

What's the right way to set this up with two individual apple developer memberships?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two developer memberships to use same bundle identifier in two different Macs. Most probably your B developer is logged in using his Apple ID which is now associated with two developer programs and trying to use his own signing certificate with developer A's provisioning profile. That won't work.

Apps need following things to build on a device or to archive.

1. A valid signing certificate
2. A bundle identifier
3. A valid provisioning profile which links step #1 and step #2

Your developer B can not use a signing certificate created with his account and link it with your developer A's provisioning profile.

**These are the steps you should follow now:** *(Note these steps are only for distribution certificates required for archiving process. If your dev B wants to build on device, then you have to do these step for developer certificates too.)*

1. You will find a signing certificate with 6UM2GR5MVA id in dev A's keychain. Format should be `"iPhone Distribution: Develper_Name_Here (6UM2GR5MVA)"` Export that signing certificate and import it to developer B's keychain. (both public and private keys together).
2. Send correct distribution provisioning profile to develper B. Or they can log into developer portal and download it from there. Then click it to open in Xcode.
3. Now go to your Xcode project settings section and open 'Signing and Capabilities' section. And select correct team with 6UM2GR5MVA id. (You might have to untick 'automatically manage signing' checkbox). Under 'Signing(Release)' section, select correct provisioning profile.
4. If those fields are not editable in step #3 you have to do this in 'build settings' section because sometimes Xcode gets confused when you use multiple accounts.
5. When distributing select the correct Distribution Certificate and Profile which should now appear in the list.

You have to repeat these steps (#1 to #4) for Developer Signing Certificate as well to set correct settings in 'Signing(Debug)' section.